# Safari iOS 15 mobile: fixed element jumps when bottom bar disappears

Tags: css, css-position, mobile-safari, fixed, ios15

Say we have a fixed sidebar, this:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 17em;
  height: 100%;
}
```

When the Safari bottom bar is visible it's ok, but when scrolling down it disappears and the sidebar remains for a while where it was and then jumps to fill the space below. It looks very buggy.

I tried to replace `height` with each one of the below solutions but none worked:

```
height: 100vh; // Sidebar is under the bottom bar

height: -webkit-fill-available; // Sidebar doesn't adjust its height

height: var(--window-inner-height); // CSS prop set via JS window.innerHeight. Same above

bottom: 0;
```

Any idea to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the environment variable `safe-area-inset-bottom` in your bottom margin or padding.

You can see an example in [this video by Jen Simmons](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10029/) (see from 16:44 min)

Comment: Adding a code sample would be helpful here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `dvh` (dynamic viewport height).

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 17em;
  height: 100dvh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
.pb-safe {
  padding-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```